AppDomains when running from memory
I understand why this fails but can anyone explain to me a possible workaround for such. There's gotta be a way to still use AppDomains while running entirely from memory. I've looked into load contexts, which should work; However, they are only available in .NET Core and I need support for .NET Framework.
This is the basic setup:
using System;

public class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello from domain '{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName}'!");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[*] Creating domain ...");
        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("[*] Creating instance ...");
        var runner = (Proxy) domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Proxy).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Proxy).FullName);
        
        Console.WriteLine("[*] Invoking method ...");
        runner.Test();
    }
 }

Executed via powershell oneliner:
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('$base64_assm')).EntryPoint.Invoke($null, $null)

Output:
[*] Creating domain ...
[*] Creating instance ...
Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'inmem, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load([System.Convert]::FromBase64String ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

The CLR seems to probe the disk for the entry assembly (inmem) which has already been loaded into (the main domain's) memory. Any thoughts?

As I remember correctly, binary file is a requirement for running separate appdomains. Honestly, if you can wrap whatever you want to run into simple service - you will save many brain cells. They are a lot more fluent/easy to support. I once had same requirement to make dynamic Razor (generate html by cshtml) service, after struggling with IPC and unhandled AppDomain errors /malicious code injections with all this Thread.Abort/Environment.Exit/leakages/marshaling garbage - I just switched to temporary services and never regret it.
